# Symfony routing with an API Web Service

Tags: php, api, routes, symfony1

I'm finishing the API of our web service. Now I'm thinking on how to make the route changes, so if we decide to make a new version we don't break the first API.

right now:

```
url: /api/:action
param: { module: api, action: :action }
requirements:
  sf_format: (?:xml|json)
```

what i've thought:

```
url: /api/v1/:module/:action
param: { module: api1, action: :action }
requirements:
  sf_format: (?:xml|json)

url: /api/v2/:module/:action
param: { module: api2, action: :action }
requirements:
  sf_format: (?:xml|json)
```

That's easy, but the perfect solution would be to have the following kind of route

```
# Automatically redirects to one module or another
url: /api/v:version/:module/:action
param: { module: api:version, action: :action }
requirements:
  sf_format: (?:xml|json)
```

any ideas on how to do it? what do you recommend us to do?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach of having 2 routes, one with v1 on it and another with v2 is the better solution. It may sound like redoing work, but if u start to think, the reason to have to versons is that the first is imcompatible with second. So, mix the 2 logics would be an overkill. If you think in some day in the future when u can have 3 version, how do you think your logic will look like?

The better solution is to make the both separate, so if u need to stop doing support for version 1 it will be easy as remove the file for version 1. =)

Comment: that's what I end up doing 2 years ago. How quick the time passes!

Answer (score 1):

How about just use the old routing rules and append .xml1/.xml2/.json1/.json2 to the end? That way you can reuse your current modules and only need to create a new view ("indexSuccess.xml1.php").

Or create a new routing class?

Comment: that's a very good idea, but that only works if the controller action does the same thing in both cases. If they are slightly different I would need if/else to check versions to search for another param, or returning a different array, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a custom route collection, as shown [here](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/02-Advanced-Routing#chapter_02_sub_replacing_the_routes_with_a_route_collection).

This would allow you to match any routing needs you have. You could move the version logic to the route class and route collection class.